# Need to do Substring in java

Tags: java

I want to do the substring of given string.
String input = select **col1,col2,(select col3 from tbl1 where 1=1),col5,col6** from tbl2 where 1=1 and col1= 'testcond' and exists (select col7 from tbl3 where 1=1 and 2=2);

Substring output should be charcters which are mark as bold.(From Col1 upto col6)
Please help me with java method which I can use.

Comment: SO is not a homework solver, put some effort and write with problems you encounter, not asking for ready solutions !

Comment: Your question itself has an answer, you need to use `substring` method, Google on it for more information.

Comment: I had tried by spliting string with comma and then traverse the string to find "from".

Comment: The input string I am getting at run time. So if it fix I could be using substring. I was assking for simple help to build the logic nothing else

Comment: input = input.substring(7);

Comment: I was trying for the logic as follows : 

String input = "select col1,col2,(select col3 from tbl1 where 1=1),col5,col6 from tbl2 where 1=1 and col1= 'testcond' and exists (select col7 from tbl3 where 1=1 and 2=2)";

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
    if (input.charAt(i) == character) {
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s"); 
 while (s.hasNext()) {
  if(s.next().equals("FROM")){
 }
    }
}

Comment: Thanks Kevin for help. But I need two range. input = input.substring(7,????);  Because input string will be runtime and if I do like this  input = input.substring(7,<upto from after col6>);  Their are three froms in the string one after col2 and one after col6 in select clause. but one more from present after where clause. I need to reach the second "from"  which is present after col6.

Answer (score 0):

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) for `String.substring()` should give you all the help you need on substring. If it turns out, that you need something else look for other methods of `String`, e.g. `split()`

Comment: Their are three froms in the string one after col2 and one after col6 in select clause. but one more from present after where clause. I need to reach the second "from" which is present after col6.